# Android: How to set onClickListener to different button when clicked

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have ten buttons and only one of them has a Red background at any point of time and the red button has an onClicklistener.
When this red button is clicked one of these ten buttons in random will get red background and this new red button should use the previous onCLickListener and when this new red button is clicked again one of these ten buttons in random gets red background and the onClickListener should be assigned to it and there is a counter which counts every time the RedButton is clicked.

Example: 
There are four buttons
[WhiteButton WhiteButton RedButton WhiteButton] and only RedButton has onClickListener
when RedButton is clicked one of the buttons color changes to red
[WhiteButton RedButton WhiteButton WhiteButton]
when this new RedButton is clicked the buttons become
[WhiteButton WhiteButton WhiteButton RedButton]

I am able to change the color of one of the ten buttons to red when the RedButton is Clicked for the first time but not able to set the OnClickListener to the new RedButton.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    Random r = new Random();
    oddValue = r.nextInt(4 - 0);
    buttons[oddValue].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    buttons[oddValue].setOnClickListener(new ourOnClickListener(this));
```

ourOnClickListener

```
public class ourOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    MainActivity caller;
    private int count;


    public ourOnClickListener(MainActivity activity) {
        this.caller = activity;
        this.count = 0;

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        int i;
        count = count + 1;
        Random r = new Random();

        int oddValue_new = r.nextInt(4 - 0);

        caller.buttons[oddValue_new].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        caller.ourTextView.setText("Count : " + count);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way as you set the background color:

```
caller.buttons[oddValue_new].setOnClickListener(this);
```

Since you are the onClickListener you can refer to this as the new onClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want only Red button is possible to click. You can set Enabled    to false for all (exclude Red button). So, you will    setOnClickListener to all button.
- If all button possible to click, only run action when Red is clicked. You should check clicked button and compare if it is Red    button in event Click
- Remove OnClickListener from all button 'setOnClickListener(null)', and SetOnClickListener to Red

Comment: I guess you misunderstood his question.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this a little bit differently.

1. Save the reference to button with red background `redButton`.
2. All buttons have the same `onClick`. In `onClick` just verify that clicked button is the one with red background (just check by reference). If not - do nothing. If yes: select new button, change background and save reference to new button.

Your `onClick` method should looks like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == redButton) {
        redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        Random r = new Random();
        int oddValue_new = r.nextInt(4 - 0);
        redButton = buttons[oddValue_new];
        redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } 
}
```

**UPDATE**

As @Mr Phuc 87 suggested you can use `enabled`. I think it is very good approach. In addition to `enabled` you can use [state-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). Create state-list which have white background for `android:state_enabled=false` and red background for `android:state_enabled=true`. Now all you need is just change `enabled` property of your buttons.

`OnClick` should looks like:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    redButton.setEnabled(false);
    Random r = new Random();
    int oddValue_new = r.nextInt(4 - 0);
    redButton = buttons[oddValue_new];
    redButton.setEnabled(true);

}
```

`state-list` should looks like(put it in `drawable`):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable=@color/white />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable=red_here />
</selector>
```